# You cant specify target table 'tbl_prod' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I would like to update the prod_qty with its current qty + the qty from another table;

it is running in workbench with SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; but when i try to run it in VB.net an error occured saying

> You cant specify target table 'tbl_prod' for update in FROM clause

Here's the query

```
Update tbl_prod 
set prod_qty = prod_qty+
    (Select itp_needQty 
     from tbl_itmonpur 
     where itp_prodID = prod_id 
     and itp_status = 'PENDING' 
     and itp_InvoiceNo = 1004) 
where prod_id = 
    (Select itp_prodID 
     from tbl_itmonpur 
     where itp_prodID = prod_id 
     and itp_status = 'PENDING' 
     and itp_InvoiceNo = 1004);
```

I'm just a student so please be easy on me :) thank you!

```
con.Open()
 qry = "UPDATE tbl_prod " + _
 "Join tbl_itmonpur " + _
 "ON tbl_itmonpur.itp_prodID = tbl_prod.prod_id " + _
 "SET tbl_prod.prod_qty = tbl_prod.prod_qty + tbl_itmonpur.itp_needQty " + _
 "WHERE tbl_itmonpur.itp_status = 'PENDING' AND tbl_itmonpur.itp_InvoiceNo @InvoiceNo; "
 cmd = New MySqlCommand(qry, con)
With cmd
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceNo", txtInvoicePend.Text)
End With
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the needed quantity is from `tbl_itmonpur` table where the `itp_prodID` column value matches `prod_id` column of `tbl_prod` table, so you need to join both tables as below

```
UPDATE tbl_prod 
JOIN tbl_itmonpur 
    ON tbl_itmonpur.itp_prodID = tbl_prod.prod_id
SET tbl_prod.prod_qty = tbl_prod.prod_qty + tbl_itmonpur.itp_needQty
WHERE tbl_itmonpur.itp_status = 'PENDING' 
AND tbl_itmonpur.itp_InvoiceNo = 1004;
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and again it works on Workbench but not in  vb.net

It says You cant specify target table 'tbl_prod' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I did Sir :) maybe there is something wrong with my Solution in vb.net ?

Comment: I've Found the solution sir, sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for the query. I refresh the bin of my Project in vb.net

Comment: I think you forgot the `=` sign, it should be `tbl_itmonpur.itp_InvoiceNo = @InvoiceNo`. You also forgot `SET` before `tbl_prod.prod_qty = tbl_prod.prod_qty + tbl_itmonpur.itp_needQty`